# Can I enable H.264 video in Chrome on the Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, h.264, html5

I left Chrome for a while because I was annoyed about Google taking away H.264 support. I won't go into my reasons why, but I'm considering using Chrome more as my default browser again.

The problem is, I still want native H.264 support in the browser since so many sites (YouTube, which Google runs, yeah...) don't provide WebM HTML5 video.

I know there's a plugin for Windows that Microsoft were kind enough to release, but what about us Mac users?

Answer (score 0):

Google have said that they will remove H.264 support from Chrome, but, as far as I know, they have yet to do it ([at least up to May](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/05/11/android_market_movie_rentals_use_flash/)). In short, it ought to work out the box, without any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension such as [Play in QuickTime](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-in-quicktime/ddiagmhagfncfocobaicfambbajngmjn).

The other alternative is to compile Chromium with your custom ffmpeg library that does support H.264